# Can Genymotion gradle plugin devices be launched in batches?

Tags: android, gradle, genymotion

I have three devices defined in the genymotion section of my `build.gradle` :

```
apply plugin: "genymotion"

genymotion {

devices {
    "Google Nexus 5 - 5.1.0 - API 22 - 1080x1920" {
        template String.valueOf(it)
        deleteWhenFinish false
    }

    "Google Nexus 7 - 4.2.2 - API 17 - 800x1280" {
        template String.valueOf(it)
        deleteWhenFinish false
    }

    "Google Nexus 9 - 5.1.0 - API 22 - 2048x1536" {
        template String.valueOf(it)
        deleteWhenFinish false
    }
}

config {
    genymotionPath = "/Applications/Genymotion.app/Contents/MacOS/"
    taskLaunch = "connectedCheck"
    }
}

connectedCheck.dependsOn genymotionLaunch
connectedCheck.mustRunAfter genymotionLaunch
genymotionFinish.mustRunAfter connectedCheck
```

When I run `./gradlew connectedCheck` all three are launched and tests ran on them simultaneously. If I wanted to add all devices that I'd like to test my app on, that list would grow to 20+ devices which my machine would not cope with. Therefore, I need a way to launch these tests in batches, of say 3. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: so you're already writing bash script and you want to run these three devices, right?

Comment: I am running these three devices, however I'd like an option to run them one-by-one, or in other sets of batches, as opposed to all simultaneously.

Comment: First notice, you should not be supposed to add the genymotion tasks dependencies. If you use genymotion gradle plugin version 1.1 or more everything should work fine.

Comment: Second notice, you don't need to precise the `genymotionPath` on Mac and Windows when the software is installed at the default location. Same for the `taskLaunch` property. The plugin sets all of this for you :-)

Comment: Concerning your problem, this use case is not handled by the plugin today, not sure it will be in the future but it is possible to implement it "by hand". I'll try to send a snipet as soon as I can.

Comment: @eyal-lezmy Thank you for the reply. I have solved this problem by creating flavors and assigning them to a group of devices I am able to launch simultaneously. I have also fixed the glaring errors in my genymotion.config block, in the meantime.

Comment: Yep dealing with flavors is a quick fix that can do the job very well if your flavors set is not too big. Nice choice! You should post your solution on the post so others can take profit of it.

Comment: I am in the process of writing a blog post, and I will post a snippet here too. Thank you :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be achieved by creating productFlavors just for tests:

```
productFlavors {
    dev; // dev/smoke tests
    api18; api19; api21; // all api levels tests
}
```

These will produce separate test tasks that can be launched separately or in succession:

```
task allConnectedAndroidTests(type: GradleBuild) {
tasks = [
        'connectedApi18DebugAndroidTest',
        'connectedApi19DebugAndroidTest',
        'connectedApi21DebugAndroidTest'
    ]
}
```

Simply assign a buildFlavor to your one, or more devices:

```
"Google Nexus 5 - 5.1.0 - API 22 - 1080x1920" {
    template String.valueOf(it)
    productFlavors "api21"
}

"Google Nexus 7 - 4.2.2 - API 17 - 800x1280" {
    template String.valueOf(it)
    productFlavors "api18"
}
```

And when you launch one of the assigned launch tasks, only the assigned devices will be launched and have the tests ran on them. For example:

```
./gradlew allConnectedAndroidTests
...
<...>genymotionLaunchConnectedApi18DebugAndroidTest
<...>connectedApi18DebugAndroidTest
<...>genymotionFinishConnectedApi18DebugAndroidTest
...
<...>genymotionLaunchConnectedApi19DebugAndroidTest
<...>connectedApi19DebugAndroidTest
<...>genymotionFinishConnectedApi19DebugAndroidTest
...
<...>genymotionLaunchConnectedApi21DebugAndroidTest
<...>connectedApi21DebugAndroidTest
<...>genymotionFinishConnectedApi21DebugAndroidTest
...
BUILD SUCCESSFUL
```

Full source of this example: https://github.com/tomaszrykala/Genymotion-productFlavors/blob/master/app/build.gradle

Answer (score 0):

According to `Genymotion` documentation:

> #### How do I start a virtual device from a command prompt?
>
> To start a virtual device from a command prompt:
>
> 1. Retrieve the list of available virtual devices by running:
>
>    - Windows: `<Genymotion installer path>\genyshell -c "devices list"`
>
>      Genymotion default installation path is `C:\Program Files\Genymobile\Genymotion.`
>    - Mac OS X: `/Applications/Genymotion.app/Contents/MacOS/genyshell -c "devices list"`
>    - Linux: `<Genymotion installer path>/genyshell -c "devices list"`
> 2. Start one of the virtual devices by running:
>
>    - Windows: `<Genymotion installer path>\player --vm-name "<virtual device name>"`
>    - Mac OS X: `/Applications/Genymotion.app/Contents/MacOS/player --vm-name "<virtual device name>"`
>    - Linux: `<Genymotion installer path>/player --vm-name "<virtual device name>"`
>
> From: https://www.genymotion.com/#!/support?chapter=start-virtual-devices-command-prompt#faq

You can after checking list of devices, run a specific one, then test by Gradle plugin, after that using `adb` shutdown and run another:

Here's an example of running

```
./genyshell -c "devices list"

./genymotion/player --vm-name "Motorola Moto X - 4.4.4 - API 19 - 720x1280"
```

To kill emulator use:

```
pkill player
```

Hope it help